PBI REST API GET requests skip limitations
I need to take all Reports from PBI and i extract them with REST API. Further then i need to take all users for each Report and their 'reportUserAccessRight'. The API for users have limitation to 200 requests per hour and i have 23 000+ reports (which is 113h.+)
Documentation link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/reports-get-report-users-as-admin
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/reports-get-reports-as-admin
My question is can i somehow skip this limitation or to get all users for each report and their rights.
Further more i need to do the same thing for dashboards and datasets which also are 10k+.
I see that 'users' can be return as additional column from workspaceAPI:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/groups-get-groups-as-admin,
but it contains 'groupUserAccessRight' which i need it but for mu user_workspace_access_rights
